# How to use parenthesis in ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

This code works:

```
 if(itemNm2!== "total"  )
```

but

```
if((itemNm2!== "total" ) || (itemNm2!== "normal(total)"))
```

doesn't work.

is is because parenthesis is used?

this is full code.

```
 var rows = resp.Sttsapitbldata[1].row;
    if (rows) {
        var representativeRow;
        for (i = 2; i < Object.keys(rows).length; i++) {
            representativeRow = rows[i];
        itemNm2 = representativeRow.ITM_NM;
        dataV = representativeRow.DTA_VAL;
        if((itemNm2!== "total" ) || (itemNm2!== "normal(total)") ){

            options.data.data.push({DTA_VAL: dataV, ITM_NM: itemNm2});
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you get a console error? the code looks valid

Comment: where is the ternary operator?

Comment: May be error is because you are not closing the main if parenthesis.

Comment: I think there is logical error you want to use && instead of || in if condition.

Comment: I think you need to remove double code from if condition if not then is the "normal(total)" is string you are comparing

Comment: Condition Code seems OK. Please check whether IF parenthesis is closed properly or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if((itemNm2!== "total" ) || (itemNm2!== "normal(total)") )
```

It always return *true*. I think right code :

```
if((itemNm2!== "total" ) && (itemNm2!== "normal(total)") )
```